# Chrome [Violation] 'load' handler took 808ms

Tags: google-chrome, openlayers-3

I worked with openlayer3. Now I got this kind of warning:
Console:

```
[Violation] 'load' handler took 308ms  ol-debug.js.xhtml?ln=js:6967 
[Violation] 'load' handler took 808ms
ol.events.bindListener_ = function(listenerObj) {
  var boundListener = function(evt) { // <- Zeile 6967
    var listener = listenerObj.listener;
    var bindTo = listenerObj.bindTo || listenerObj.target;
    if (listenerObj.callOnce) {
      ol.events.unlistenByKey(listenerObj);
    }
    return listener.call(bindTo, evt);
  };
  listenerObj.boundListener = boundListener;
  return boundListener;
};
```

Is it maybe a bug on Google Chrome?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The message `[Violation] 'load' handler took x ms` seems more like a warning that your code took a long time to run, than anything else. Perhaps you should try to move the code execution out of the load handler, and into something else (a button click?).